# data.table: Merging nearby genomic features

Tags: r, data.table

I'm exploring using data.table for doing computations on genomic intervals as an alternative to GenomicRanges.

I have the following issue:
For a (very large) BED-file like this:

```
data.table(chr=c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr3"),
                     start=c(8, 10, 20, 7, 10, 30),
                     end=c(9, 12, 25, 13, 12, 40),
                     strand=c("+", "+", "-", "+", "-", "+"),
                     score=c(1.2, 3.2, 0.5, 6.0, 1.0, 9.0))
```

Looking like:

```
    chr start end strand score
1: chr1     8   9      +   1.2
2: chr1    10  12      +   3.2
3: chr1    20  25      -   0.5
4: chr2     7  13      +   6.0
5: chr2    10  12      -   1.0
6: chr3    30  40      +   9.0
```

I want to merge nearby features/ranges: Features that are on the same chromosome and strand and within X distance are grouped, and some calculation are performed on their scores. For the above example, the two first features would be merged and their score summed:

```
    chr start end strand score
1: chr1     8  12      +   4.4
2: chr1    20  25      -   0.5
3: chr2     7  13      +   6.0
4: chr2    10  12      -   1.0
5: chr3    30  40      +   9.0
```

Assuming that the none of the input features overlap, is there an easy way to do this using data.table?

The problem can be solved by using the coverage-, slice- and reduce-functions in GenomicRanges, but I'm specifically interested in a data.table solution.

Answer (score 0):

With no intersections you can do smth like this:

```
setorder(dt, chr, start)

# adjust the comparison to suit your needs
dt[, grp := cumsum(c(F, head(end, -1) + 1 != tail(start, -1))), by = chr]

dt[, .(start = start[1], end = end[.N], strand = strand[1], score = sum(score))
   , by = .(chr, grp)]
#    chr grp start end strand score
#1: chr1   0     8  12      +   4.4
#2: chr1   1    20  25      -   0.5
#3: chr2   0     7  13      +   6.0
#4: chr2   1    10  12      -   1.0
#5: chr3   0    30  40      +   9.0
```